# How to calculate the number of duplicated elements in a nested list in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following DataFrame in PySpark:

```
+----------+------------------------+
|        id|              codes_list|
+----------+------------------------+
|      FF10|   [[1049, 1683], [108]]|
|      AB36|        [[1507], [1005]]|
|      8266|[[1049], [1049], [1049]]|
+----------+------------------------+
```

This is the schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codes_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I calculate the number of duplicated codes in `codes_list`?

This is the expected result:

```
+----------+----+
|        id| qty|
+----------+----+
|      FF10|   0|
|      AB36|   0|
|      8266|   1|
+----------+----+
```

Comment: For spark 2.4+ there might be approach using [`flatten`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) and [`array_distinct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct) and looking at the size difference between the flattened and distinct...

Comment: @pault: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but I think that there might be a problem with data types. Please see the schema (I updated my post). It seems that in my original DataFrame the sub-arrays are recognized as strings...

Comment: Difference between the size of flattened and distinct arrays gives the number of duplicates, not the number of duplicated values...

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to explode those numbers and count each occurrence of `id`, `code`. Then group by `id` and use conditional sum to get the number of duplicated values.

As the array contains strings and not sub-arrays, you could, first, remove the square brackets and split by `,` to get the codes.

```
data = [("FF10", ["[1049, 1683]", "[108]"]),
        ("FAB36", ["[1507]", "[1005]"]),
        ("8266", ["[1049]", "[1049]", "[1049]"])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "codes_list"])


df.withColumn("codes", explode("codes_list")) \
  .withColumn("codes", explode(split(regexp_replace("codes", "[\\[\\]]", ""), ","))) \
  .groupBy("id", "codes").count() \
  .groupBy("id").agg(sum((col("count") > lit(1)).cast("int")).alias("qty")) \
  .show()
```

Gives:

```
+-----+---+
|   id|qty|
+-----+---+
| FF10|  0|
| 8266|  1|
|FAB36|  0|
+-----+---+
```